# 'Undeclared Identifier' error with defined constants

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My defined constants are giving me 'undeclared identifier' issues. I have them in a `Constants.h` file that I am including in my .pch file. I thought it might be something with my .pch file, however, if I delete it from there and try `#import` it in one of the classes where I need one of the constants, then I still get an 'undeclared identifier' error.

If I take each `#define` line and put them at the top of the .m class file directly, they work. So my syntax is correct.

So it's something with the .h file itself, but I have no idea what.

```
//
//  Constants.h

// Sliding Drawer
#define kOffscreenX 320    // X coord when Sliding Drawer is offscreen
#define kVisibleX 40       // X coord when Sliding Drawer is visible

// WordlistButton
#define kNumScores 3

// Fonts
#define kMessageFontSize 14
#define kScoreFontSize 10
```

Comment: try to remove comments from the lines with #define statement

Comment: I tried to delete everything except for one line, and it still doesn't recognize that one defined constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to see the error only from this piece of code. Preprocessor tends to create very messy things, especially when there are circular imports involved.

You can try to delete the current compiled version of the header, note it's not in the `derived data` folder, it's in XCode's cache (see Project -> Build Setttings -> Precompiled Headers Cache Path).

However, if you have tried to import `Constants.h` directly and it didn't work, the problem may be somewhere else.

Are you sure there is only 1 file called `Constants.h`? Note you should use a prefix for your files (e.g. `SAConstants.h` if `Smooth Almonds` is your name) to avoid collision with Apple's headers or headers of the libraries you are using.

If you import the header directly, go to the `.m` file and tap on `Product -> Generate Output -> Preprocessed File` and find `Constants.h` import in it. Is it your header?

By the way, there is a nice article about avoiding this kind of things in precompiled headers http://qualitycoding.org/precompiled-headers/

Comment: +1 Not only an answer, few more things to learn from. Another good answer from @Sulthan

Comment: I did have more than one Constants.h. I had run a search for it in the Project Navigator, but nothing came up, so I assumed there wasn't a second one. However, there were not 1 but 2 Constants.h headers in my file directory. I assumed only files added to the Project Navigator, and not just in the file directory, were ever really 'seen' by XCode, but I guess that's wrong.

Comment: @SmoothAlmonds When building, XCode passes the header folders to the compiler, not the individual files. And the compiler doesn't know which one of the files should be used and takes the first it finds.

Comment: @Sulthan I have a similar problem but I already checked I don't have any `Constants.h`. The problem starts when I include pjsip library (.a and headers) into my framework project. My C constants like `errno`, `NAN`, `M_PI` got a `Use of undeclared identifier` error, and methods like `strerror()` got `Implicitly declaring library function` warnings all over the place. I run out of ideas now :(

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread due to an other error `upper case parameter` in my define statement. I solved it for my issue with lower casing:

```
#define MSB(BTvalue) ((uint8_t) (BTvalue >> 8))  //threw this error
```

changing **BTvalue** to just **value** with **lowercase** parameter made me happy

```
#define MSB(value) ((uint8_t) (value >> 8))
```